# Software for cloning folders with their original names (without their subfolders ‎and contents)

Tags: copy-paste

I have many folders (about one hundred) with various names and each folder has ‎many subfolders and single files in its. Now I need to copy and clone them ‎*without their subfolders and contents* (just folders with their original names) and ‎then move and paste to another machine’s drive or another my drive on my own machine. If I sit and create new folders ‎and give them the specific names one by one, it could be a boring and time-‎consuming job. Now I’m looking for software to create and clone the folders ‎quickly and immediately. If there’s a magical software for my need that compatible ‎with Windows 10 OS?‎

Comment: It seems like the default PowerShell can do it, see, for example, [Copy folders without files, files without folders, or everything using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996649/copy-folders-without-files-files-without-folders-or-everything-using-powershel)

Comment: Thank you for the link @homocomputeris. But I'm not familiar with Powershell and this kind of code-writing environment things and I should confess I hate these ways! I run Powershell and tried some commands, but didn't get any answer! I'm sure I don't know how to use it correctly and need software to do it for me by a few clicks!